# Username is not appearing on an SE site

Tags: support, bug, login, user-accounts

I have accounts on 15 SE websites, and although I haven't checked them all, I'm fairly sure that my "Leo King" alias is visible on all but one of them. For some reason on the science fiction and fantasy SE I appear as [user25915](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/25915/user25915). I created this account the same way as every other account, by logging in and connecting to my stackexchange account using the same email address and password. Can you suggest any reasons why this may occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution - I edited my profile on a site where my username appears properly, and clicked save and copy to all stack exchange accounts. Now my username appears properly on the scifi SE. I don't know if the bug or the solution are repeatable.